# In Crash Reporter what's the difference between an Exception Type and an Exception Code and why are there multiple codes?

Tags: c++, macos, crash-reports

In Crash Reporter 
1. What's the difference between an Exception Type and an Exception Code. 
2. Why are there multiple codes?
3. Where should I look to decode them?
4. How does an EXC_BREAKPOINT exception gain two error codes when INT3 doesn't look like it takes an error codes.

For example I have this one right now:

```
Exception Type: EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
```

I've done some digging ...  Possibly the exception codes are listed here:

https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-2050.22.13/osfmk/mach/kern_return.h

Apple helpfully provide this note which says:

> "Exception Codes: Processor specific information about the exception
>   encoded into one or more 64-bit hexadecimal numbers. **Typically, this
>   field will not be present** because the Crash Reporter parses the
>   exception codes to present them as a human-readable description in the
>   other fields."

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2151/_index.html

Well sure - but it's present in my crash report log.

Maybe these are the codes Intel describe here:

> "An exception is an event that typically occurs when an instruction
>   causes an error. For example, an attempt to divide by zero generates
>   an exception. However, some exceptions, such as breakpoints, occur
>   under other condi- tions. Some types of exceptions may provide error
>   codes. An error code reports additional information about the error.
>   An example of the notation used to show an exception and error code is
>   shown below:  #PF(fault code)

But Vol 2A 3-471 of the Intel processor manual says that the breakpoint exception doesn't take a fault code.

So I'm lost.

Comment: Can consult here  - http://www.5neo.be/understanding-ios-exception-types/

Comment: Could do, have done, but it's IOS and doesn't really explain the stuff I need to know.  Also __builtin_trap() seems to cause a SIGILL not a SIGTRAP on Intel. So thanks but still lost :)

Comment: This is debugging related. Thus, could be almost anything. Provided the link above, because it gives some general way for understanding.